# How to use noty library in angular

Tags: angular, noty

[Noty](https://ned.im/noty/) is a amazing library for show notification in app that i try to use it now in my angular application

by attention to [Noty Documentation](https://ned.im/noty/#/installation) i installed it by npm and import in my component

```
import * as Noty from 'noty';
```

and use it in **ngOnInit**

```
new Noty({
      text: 'NOTY - a dependency-free notification library!',
  }).show();
```

but when i run application it is not work correctly and just show my message in div.noty_body tag and css classes not used at all

Comment: Have you already  added <script src="path/to/noty.js"></script> in index.html?

Comment: You might want to use an angular port of noty ( https://github.com/HVND/ng-noty )

Comment: @SebaCherian no i didnt link this but i installed by npm. still needed to link directly in index.html ?

Comment: @Carsten oh there is no way to use Noty directly in angular yet?

Comment: @Ali Please make a try

Comment: @SebaCherian I try this way but not work. first i try to link noty from node module folder and it failed, second i copy noty.css and noty.js in my assets folder and link from there but still didnt work correctly